# Find the numbers with exactly 2 nines in them

Tags: c++

We input n numbers and the program must type the ones that have exactly 2 ‘9’ in them. (for instance, if we input 9193 then the program will type it, but if we write 73999 or 256 it will not give any output).
So I wrote this code

```
int main(){
int a, n, i, count=0, y;
cin>>n;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
    cin>>a; y=a;
    while(y>0){
       if(y%10==9) count++;
       y=y/10;
   }
   if(count==2) cout<<a<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

But I cannot understand why this does not work.
If I change it and write this way it works.

```
int main(){
int a, n, i, count, y;
cin>>n;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
             count=0;
    cin>>a; y=a;
    while(y>0){
       if(y%10==9) count++;
       y=y/10;
   }
   if(count==2) cout<<a<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Will much appreciate if you explain this to me.

Comment: You have to reset `count` for each new number as each number has its own count of nines. What is confusing about that?

Comment: Oh, it was that simple :) thanks for the help :)

Comment: Read each "number" into a `std::string`. It's much easier to count characters that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just read as string (or convert it to) and count:

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
   std::string numstr;
   std::cin >> numstr; 
   if( std::count( numstr.begin(), numstr.end(), '9' ) == 2 )
      std::cout << numstr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yup possibly the expense of performance which is probably not relevant, and might be hogwash since cin has to convert the buffer to an int anyway if you wanted that type to receive the data. And your solution works for negative numbers. (Which the OP’s will not even once the trivial bug is fixed.) Have an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't reset `count` to `0` each time through the main loop, you're adding the count in the new number to the count from the previous number.

So if you type `19` for the first number, you'll set `count` to `1`. Then if you type `939` for the second number, it will set `count` to `3`, and the test `if (count == 2)` will not succeed, even though there were 2 nines in that number. After this, `count` will never become `2`, because you'll keep adding to it.

You need to start counting from the beginning for each number.

Note that your algorithm won't work for negative numbers. `-9 % 10` is `-9`, not `9`.

Comment: Don’t forget to mention the bug with negative input.

Answer (score -1):

We need to initialise `count=0` for every case.